# Does toasting Thomas's English Muffins make that toaster dairy?

Tags: meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization

Thomas's English muffins contain whey from a [dairy source](http://www.fooducate.com/app#!page=product&id=09A39E2C-E10C-11DF-A102-FEFD45A4D471).

Does toasting the muffin make the toaster dairy?

Concern:

- Is the amount of dairy in the muffin less than 1/60 of the ingredients?

Comment: Are you asking 1) if milchig things in a toaster make the toaster milchig or 2) if these muffins are really milchig, or 3) if they're milchig enough to make the toaster milchig assuming #1 is true? Not clear.

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/dairy-english-muffins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the author of [this article](http://shaareihoraah.org/wordpress/?p=604):

> Thomas’ English Muffins are not really Milchig at all. While they d
>   contain dairy ingredients, they constitute less than 1/60th of the
>   total mixture and are Batel.

It is worthwhile reading the whole article as it addresses the question of eating dairy "bread" and how that applies specifically to this specific product.

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why something with less than 1/60 dairy could be eaten with meat, but something cooked in a dairy kli could not?

Comment: I remember it's something about how the whole kli is 100% dairy and makes the food ~~100% dairy but I don't remember exactly what.

Comment: AND re: this article... He's relying on the fact that these muffins contain less than 1/60 dairy to say that one could eat them with meat. But what if they were also prepared in a dairy kli, as I imagine they probably were?

Comment: @SAH If a kli gives off less than 1/60th dairy then that food can be eaten with milk. Since it's hard to measure how much dairy comes out of a kli and we usually don't know, the custom is to be strict such that the food would need to be 60 times the volume of the whole kli, which is the theoretical maximum amount of dairy that could be in the kli. But if I take a new pot, boil 1 teaspoon of milk, then boil 61 teaspoons of chicken soup, that chicken soup is still kosher since I know there's less milk than 1/60 of the soup.

Comment: @DoubleAA Great explanation; thanks. One thing I don't get, then, is why many people would be meikel on keilim (in terms of waiting between meat and milk, etc.) if it's actually worse than having <1/60

Comment: @SAH I don't know what you mean by "meikel on keilim". Also recall waiting between meat and milk is not a biblical requirement. Biblically you just can't eat a cooked mixture of them.